# delete exe files smaller than a specific size

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I would like to delete all exe files whose size is less than 400 kb in one folder, either with a batch file of VBScript.

I tried this one, but it is not working:

```
@echo off setlocal
for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %%A in (`dir /b *.exe`) do If %%~zA LSS 3145728 del "%%A"
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to remove viruses....  :)

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@echo off 
setlocal
for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %%A in (`dir /b *.exe`) do If %%~zA LSS 3145728 ECHO del "%%A"
for /f  "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b *.exe') do If %%~zA LSS 409600 ECHO del "%%A"

GOTO :EOF
```

Other than the `setlocal` should be on a separate line (which is irrelevant) there appears to be nothing wrong with your code in principle.

I've added an `ECHO` command before the `del` - just as a safety measure to **not** delete the file but simply show its name so that you don't delete files until you're ready.

The new line I've added simply does exactly the same thing, but more simply. And you say "400K" but `3145728` is not the `400K` you mention.

You would have to run this file with the current directory=the directory from which you wish to make the deletion(s). If you're running it from a "shortcut", you'd need to add a new line

```
cd \where\to\delete\dir
```

before the `for` command.

Comment: It's a `cmd` batch file - not a VBScript file. The error code is "Invalid character". Save the file as `whatever.BAT` then execute as `whatever` from the prompt while your current directory is the directory in which you wish to delete the files.